# Is 'diverse range' a pleonastic phrase?

Tags: phrases, pleonasms

I am just curious as to whether 'diverse range' is pleonastic because a range implies that there are already different things, which implies diversity.

Is it redundant to modify 'range' with 'diverse' despite the fact that the range is already diverse? I've seen this phrase before. A simple online search reveals plenty of authors that have decided to use it in their writing.

Any answers are much appreciated.

Comment: A "range" could be all flat grassland, with nary a distinguishing feature.  Or it could include hills, a creekbed, several trees, some interesting fossils, and a alien spacecraft.  One has "distinguishing features" and the other doesn't -- can you say which is which?

Comment: I don't think range implies any meaningful amount of diversity. "A narrow range" and "a wide range" are both common expressions.

Answer (score 10):

*Diverse range* isn't pleonastic.

This is a **diverse** range of colors:

[image: blue, red, green, and purple paint strips]
<sub>[4 Vocabulary Ideas to Avoid Roadblocks](https://www.adventuresinliteracyland.com/2015/03/4-vocabulary-ideas-to-avoid-roadblocks.html)</sub>

This is **not** a diverse range of colors:

[image: grey white, brownish white, browner white, beige white, and some other white paint strips]
<sub>[Sherwin Williams Accessible Beige Exterior](http://traffic-club.info/2018simage-sherwin-williams-accessible-beige-exterior.awp)</sub>

In other words, "diverse" means a range with greater variance. It has nothing to do with the number of things in the range.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not, not innately.

A "range" is very often linear (e.g., a range of numbers).  What you get in such ranges is the same thing over and over again just in varying degrees along the line segment that constitutes the range.

Saying "diverse range," one is making a point to indicate it is not such a range, that the range is non-linear.  Imagine now instead of a range that is a line, a chart wherein there is an X-axis and a Y-axis.  The range of points fall all over the page and not all in a straight line.  That is the picture that "diverse" is painting before "range."

Therefore, by using "diverse" to modify "range," one is not being redundant when the point is to indicate that it is not a range of *sames* but a range of *differents*, as it were, so, for example, if I have a "diverse range," my collection of things in that range isn't just 3°C through 88°C, which is a range, but also includes items not anywhere on that line, like an apple, an E# played on keyboard, and a smile from across the room.

ADDITIONAL EXAMPLE:

If a radio ad were to say a dealership has simply "a range" of automobiles, that could easily be construed as a single brand, as is often the case with car dealerships, and its linear range of cars from an economy subcompact through a luxury sedan.  But if a radio ad were to say a "a diverse range" instead, it would more clearly intimate that the dealership sells cars and trucks of different brands—of various makes and models, not just a range of models of the same make.

Comment: I agree. Ring spanners, for example, come in a range of sizes but all the metric spanners in a given range differ only in size, not in material or appearance. Not only that but the spanners in a range aimed at the retail hobby market will be in a restricted range of sizes but the same manufacturer might well offer a professional range which will be more diverse both in size and style to cater for more applications.

Answer (score 2):

**diverse range** - a colocation  [Longman](http://www.longmandictionariesusa.com/laad/dictionary#range_1)

> a **diverse range** (=a number of very different things)  As in:  During his career
>   he has run a diverse range of businesses.